# Remove file extensions with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a page on my site with the URL of http://localhost/logout/.

I've  created the `/logout/` directory and the `index.php` file in that folder, but because I remove the extension of files when I go to http://localhost/logout/ it gives me a 404 error.

To actually get to the page I have to go to http://localhost/logout/index, which I don't want.

How do I fix this?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not remove the .php extension, add this to htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```